# Moving shape within the polygon

Tags: actionscript-3

Test link: http://bit.ly/Runmah

pick one item from left side for testing.

it's rotating when he find two intersect points on the line.

i want to move red rectangle within the polygon. It shouldn't go outside of polygon.

My code is: http://pastebin.com/pRMpk81f

Edit 1: http://pastebin.com/C3j4WSC1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to find the intersection of points on the line then you should be able to find distance between wall and furniture (line and edge of rectangle), you can check this value and for example stop draging and snap,

**EDIT1:**
when dragged item is selected (mouse is down) than you constantly check distance (e.g. on mouse move), then you can decide that if distance is within some threshold you will stop movement (basicaly you will set calculated position- snap - instead of applying mouse position) otherwise you will follow mouse.

**EDIT2:**
also you can test if the point is inside the shape by calculating intersection points - even number the point is outside, odd number - the point is inside

best regards

Comment: i tried that. I stopped the movement of furniture when it finds intersect point. But how can i move it again when it stopped?

Comment: updated answer - basically it is not that YOU stop the dragging - all you do is setting new position when some conditions are met.

Comment: I guess drop dragging entirely, and move via listening to MouseEvents, each time checking if out-of-bounds, if yes then rotate, if yes after rotation, then don't move (store previous position and rotation before calculations).

Comment: Thank You, I updated pastebin code and test link. Now i pushing back the object if  there are two intersection point. But at the corners it has more intersection points which is belong to another wall. So it cannot decide rotating and snapping. Do you have any idea for this issue?

Comment: always you can check which one is closer but corners are tricky:)

Comment: If you can rotate and it'll not need to get snapped, then rotate, otherwise do not rotate but snap. Also, with this your objects can leave the polygon, and also you are able to place a red rectangle over the non-convex corner of your limiting polygon :)